# How to flip the scale of just a parent GameObject and not its children

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I'm creating a 2D platformer game and I have a Player gameObject in the hierarchy that has its sprite. When the player is facing one way and they press the opposite arrow, I'd like to flip the sprite but *not* the camera and groundCheck children gameObjects underneath.

The code below doesn't work and it gives me a `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.

```
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f) {
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.parent.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }
```

When I replace `transform.parent.localScale = localScale` to `transform.localScale = localScale` it works except it flips all of the gameObjects, including the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the nature of my 2D platformer, I was able to just use the flipX boolean on the Sprite Renderer. I didn't notice it was there! This code works great:

```
private void Flip() {
    if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f) {
        isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = !isFacingRight;
    }
}
```